# Python - Invalid syntax

Tags: python, spyder

I have this error: Invalid syntax in my code below:

```
   with gzip.open('EnCorp2Million.txt.gz', 'rb') as f:
try:
    anatxt = f.read().decode('utf-8') 
except ValueError as e:
   print("Error:",e)

def strip_html(text):
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
return soup.get_text()
anatxt = strip_html(anatxt)

def remove_between_square_brackets(text):
return re.sub('\[[^]]*\]', '', text)
anatxt = remove_between_square_brackets(anatxt)

def denoise_text(text):
text = strip_html(text)
text = remove_between_square_brackets(text)
return text
anatxt = denoise_text(anatxt)

def replace_contractions(text):
   return contractions.fix(text)
anatxt = replace_contractions(anatxt)

words = nltk.word_tokenize(anatxt)

#1gram
onegram = ngrams(words, 1)
fdist_onegram = nltk.FreqDist(onegram)
for c,v in fdist_onegram.items(30):
    print (c,v)

#As c,v mais frequentes
print(fdist_onegram.most_common(30))  
print(fdist_onegram.plot(30)

#2gram
bigram = ngrams(words, 2)
fdist_bigram = nltk.FreqDist(bigram)

#As c,v mais frequentes
print(fdist_bigram.most_common(30))  
print(fdist_bigram.plot(30)
```

when executing, I am getting the error:

```
bigram = ngrams(words, 2)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I remove the bigram calculation, the error disappears, but I need to do the calculation for the 7 grams

How can I fix this?

Comment: you missed closing `)` at the line immidiate before error line

Comment: you miss a bracket here, in the line before the error  print(fdist_onegram.plot(30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see a syntax error on a line that seems fine, look at the preceding line. In this case you forgot closing parenthesis.

```
print(fdist_onegram.plot(30)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've seen it now.